# Custom setter is not called, when using databinding

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

I just run into a problem, using android databinding library.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <import type="com.test.app.ObservableFieldWrapper"/>
    <variable
        name="org"
        type="ObservableFieldWrapper"/>
</data>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">      
    <com.test.app.NSpinner
        android:id="@+id/orgSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:org="@{org.getSilent ? org.content : &quot;silent&quot;}"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my NSpinner:

```
 public class ObservableFieldWrapper{

    private final ObservableBoolean silent;

    private final ObservableField<String> content;

    @BindingAdapter("org")
    public static void setOrg(Spinner view, String org) {
        assert org != null;
        if (org.equals("silent")) {
           Log.i("ObsWrapper", "SET ORG called via binding adapter but got denied, because of SILENCE");
            } else {
                Log.i("ObsWrapper", "SET ORG called via binding adapter NORMALLY");
                view.setSelection(Cache.GetOrgIndexForSpinner(), true);
            }
    }

    public ObservableFieldWrapper(String startValue) {
        content = new ObservableField<>(startValue);
        silent = new ObservableBoolean();
        silent.set(false);
    }

    public void setContent(String newValue) {
        silent.set(false);
        content.set(newValue);
        content.notifyChange();
    }

    public void setContentSilent(String newValue) {
        silent.set(true);
        content.set(newValue);
    }

  //Bunch of getters
}
```

And this call should invoke the static getter provided, by ObservableFieldWrapper class (assume, that all bindings were already set):

```
ObservableFieldWrapper someField = new ObservableFieldWrapper("someString");
someField.setContent("some other string");
```

Well, problem is... It invokes nothing. But if I change my xml part from

```
app:org="@{org.getSilent ? org.content : &quot;silent&quot;}"
```

to common

```
app:org="@{org.content}"
```

It starts working! I realy need this extra functionality with boolean, and I am really lost trying to find the issue.

---

Found a work around, where didn't use any logics in xml expressions, I just passed 2 parameters to my function and did all job there.

```
@Bindable ("{org, silent}")
```

Yet, the question remains unanswered.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct `org.getSilent ? org.content : &quot;silent&quot;`. seems like you want `app:org='@{org.silent ? "silent" : org.content}'`

Comment: I am sure, but the way you provided is good aswell.

Comment: Are you using rc1 or rc2?

Comment: Just for kicks, instead of having private ObservableFields, make them public instead and eliminate the getters. Methods are not observable unless they are marked @Bindable and are in a class implementing Observable. Your expression will also change: app:org=`'@{org.silent ? org.content : "silent"}'`

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out next time, though, I thought auto-getters were implemented in the last version, aswell as the automatical creation of needed entries in Bind class for observablefields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As George Mount mentioned - it's important to remove any getters on observable fields, otherwise it won't work, I spent pretty much time with this issue and then mentioned that I have a getter, after removing it - everything started working.